# Keycloak SSO minimum mysql database privileges

Tags: mysql, redhat, single-sign-on

I have been trying to install `Keycloak` but instead of the usual `'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES'` command to grant access to the database to the `MySQL` database, I need the exact minimum privileges to be granted. I have been looking at Keycloak documentation for this but I did not find any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those wondering, the following privileges work:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, ALTER, REFERENCES, INDEX, DROP ON `<database>`.* TO `<user>`@`<host>`;
```